# Get dimensions of loaded item in Loader element in QML

Tags: qt, qml

If i have a Loader element in my main.qml like this:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    property int margin: 16
    visible: true
    width: pageLoader.implicitWidth
    height: pageLoader.implicitHeight

    Loader { //Loads some qml page
        id: pageLoader
        width: item.implicitWidth
        height: item.implicitHeight
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: 'TestSourcePage.qml'
        onStatusChanged: { //Approach#1
            if(pageLoader.status == Loader.Ready) {
                console.log("Ready")
                console.log(item.implicitWidth)
            }
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {//Approach#2
            console.log(pageLoader.item.width)
        }
    }
}
```

In a file called TestSourcePage.qml:

```
Item {
    Rectangle {
        color: 'red'
        width: 700
        height: 700
    }
}
```

What happens is that i'm unable to get the dimensions of the loaded rectangle, hence the dimensions of the ApplicationWindow is not set accordingly.
In both approaches (`Component.onCompleted` and `onStatusChanged`) the output of `console.log(item.implicitWidth)` or `pageLoader.item.width` is 0. I want to know the reason for this.

I don't know if this is the better way of doing. Can anyone give me some directions?

Comment: Loaded item has no size. You set size for Rectangle inside it but not for the Item itself.

Comment: Thank you. Making the rectangle the parent item just made the trick. I'll be accepting your answer to this question if you provide one. ;)